# Searching in jQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the latest jQuery Datatables and currently i am able to get the data in to the table, but every time i try to search i see no change to the table

The following is my code

```
init: function(){
    $('#paginatedData').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            url: "/bugbounty/viewreports",
            dataSrc: "reportList"
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "reportStatus"},
            {"data": "reportID", "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
                return '<a href="reportsummary">'+ data +'</a>';
            }},
            {"data": "summary"},
            {"data": "lastUpdatedDate"},
            {"data": "createdDate"}
        ]
    });

}
```

Do i need to set anymore additional values, shouldn't the search by default be set to true?

Edit: Here is my JSON response

> {reportList:[ { reportID: 'EIBBP-460',
>          eBayUserID: ' ',
>          reportStatus: 'New',
>          summary: 'BugBounty Report created by Raj',
>          lastUpdatedDate: '2015-06-16 04:27',
>          createdDate: '2015-06-16 04:27',
>          paypalLoginID: 'raaj@paypal.com' },
>        { reportID: 'EIBBP-459',
>          eBayUserID: ' ',
>          reportStatus: 'New',
>          summary: 'BugBounty Report created by Raj',
>          lastUpdatedDate: '2015-06-16 04:25',
>          createdDate: '2015-06-16 04:25',
>          paypalLoginID: 'raaj@paypal.com' }]}

Comment: Since you have server-side processing mode enabled (`"serverSide":true`), searching and filtering should be done on the [server-side](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). Does you script at `/bugbounty/viewreports` handle search request? Please post your JSON response.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com i have attached my json response to the post , how would i got about adding the searching and filtering on the server side

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing client-side and server-side processing modes. From the [manual](http://datatables.net/manual/data):

> DataTables has two different modes of processing data (ordering, searching, etc. of data):
>
> Client-side processing - the full data set is loaded up-front and data processing is done in the browser.
>
> Server-side processing - an Ajax request is made for every table redraw, with only the data required for each display returned. The data processing is performed on the server.

In both modes data can be loaded from the server, but the name implies where the procesing (pagination/ordering/filtering) will be performed.

You have server-side processing mode enabled (`"serverSide":true`), searching and filtering should be done on the server-side. Since your script isn't programmed to do so, that's why you don't see ordering/filtering working.

Your JSON response is valid for client-side processing but not for server-side processing, [see manual](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) for correct response structure.

**Solution 1: Disable server-side processing mode**

You can disable server-side processing mode if you don't have many rows in the table.  To enable client-side instead, omit `serverSide` option or set it to `false`. In this case, use the code below:

```
$('#paginatedData').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        url: "/bugbounty/viewreports",
        dataSrc: "reportList"
    },
    "columns": [
        {"data": "reportStatus"},
        {"data": "reportID", "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
            return '<a href="reportsummary">'+ data +'</a>';
        }},
        {"data": "summary"},
        {"data": "lastUpdatedDate"},
        {"data": "createdDate"}
    ]
});
```

**Solution 2: Add server-side processing**

Alternatively, if you have many rows in your table, you can still user server-side processing mode for performance, you need to adjust your script to return correct data structure based on supplied parameters.

DataTables distribution include a sample PHP scripts (`server_processing.php` and `ssp.class.php`) in `\examples\server_side\scripts\` folder to demonstrate the implementation.

Comment: that was just a sample of the data it actually returns more data than i posted, also i forgot to add dataSrc in my json i have corrected it

Comment: @Raj, I corrected the answer based on your update, `dataSrc` is correct then.

Comment: could you provide me the links where they are show the snippet for searching on the server side

Comment: what i don't understand is why i need a server side manipulation for searching and filtering

Comment: @Raj, [download the latest DataTables plug-in](http://datatables.net/download/index), sample PHP scripts (`server_processing.php` and `ssp.class.php`) are in `\examples\server_side\scripts\`.

Comment: @Raj, searching/filtering will work if you disable server-side mode (by not including `"serverSide":true` or setting `"serverSide":false`.

Comment: i am using node.js and don't understand php

Comment: I do need serverSide as i am getting the table data as a response from the server side code

Comment: @Raj, Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80702/discussion-between-gyrocode-com-and-raj).